# deleted private/var folder

Tags: macos, trash

I have done a foolish thing. I deleted `private/var` folder due to malware I was after. I immediately felt that strange things are beginning to happen so I pressed `cmd+Z` to reverse action. The computer frezzed so I shut it and rerun it. Now I cant relaunch it, because it shuts down while it is loading into my user account.

So I went to single user mode and and tried to copy the `var` folder from `.Trashes` to `private` folder. The problem is that `.Trashes` seem to be empty. Meaning that cmd-Z worked, which would mean that var folder is back in place. But the computer doesnt start. Does `ls` command dosnt show files in trash? What seems to be the problem?

Also, if this doesnt work, I am gonna have to copy important files to external disc from Single user mode. What is the path to external harddrive?

EDIT > private/var does indeed have content. I am now getting confused. Did the system put some content in there for me?

Comment: How did you delete it. Note that delete does not put things in Trash - in Finder Move to Trash does.

Comment: with cmd-backspace

Comment: That would have required you to enter an admin password as well

Comment: It did. An antivirus program pointed out a file in this folder. I inspected the folder and there were a lot of files that I knew were malware. Deleted the entire folder. I am amazed by my stupidity :D

Comment: In tat case restore from an old backup - before the malware was installed - I'll delete m=y answer as that changes everything - please put the reason in your question

Comment: Your answer was good and no reason to delete it. I am wondering, if someone else gave me the private/var folder, and I paste the contents into my private/var..would that work?

Comment: No. The best way would be recover from your own backup. Parts of private/var will regenerate, but not all & not to the state they were in previously.

Comment: My answer is wrong - if affected by malware you must assume all executable files are corrupted and start from scratch or from a known good state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume a malware infection, by all means reinstall the OS by rebooting into the Recovery Partition with <kbd>Cmd-R</kbd> and reinstall from there. This should not affect your existing users (or their files).

See [OS X: About OS X Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) for details about the procedure.